# Retrieve Image from another Intent

Tags: android

How can I retrieve an image from another `Intent` within the same application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you can use `Intent.putExtra(String, Parcelable)` and `Intent.getParcelableExtra(String)` methods to store and load image. But it's not very fast method. And if you need to transfer a large image, you'd better put it in a static field.

Comment: k....let me try......bt my whole application is when u select image from gallery...dat image should be passed to another activity...and image should have zoom out and in functionality....